# What are the neurobiological factors related to depression?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, depression, psychology

While it is agreed that neurotransmitters aren't the primary "cause" of depression, what other factors are a part of this mental illness that focus on the neurobiological aspects of it?

Comment: Welcome to cogsci.SE!  This is an interesting question, but you will generally get better responses if you frame your question using the research you've already done to try to answer the question.  Where is it agreed that neurotransmitters (and which aspect of them?) aren't the primary cause of depression?  What kinds of other factors are you thinking of?  Etc.

Comment: I concur with @Krysta 's critique, in that the serotinergic hypothesis, given the effectiveness of SSRIs, is not deemed invalid (I'm not an expert, though). See http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/how-do-ssris-work/9486#9486

Answer (score 2):

You can look into the research being done with ketamine as an amazingly fast antidepressant, even for those with severe treatment resistant depression. Other than that, they now think decreased neurogenesis and synaptogenesis are the more direct and important links to depression. There is also some early research into the links between depression and the immune system, as well as people's microbiomes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! At CognitiveSciences.SE we appreciate when answers contain some references to back up the answer and to allow folks to find additional info if need be. Thanks!